# C# RichTextBox how to change font ForegroundColor upon printing?

Tags: c#, printing, fonts, colors, richtextbox

I'm trying to use the RichTextBox (that I've modified a bit with some additions found here and there) so that when I print, my white text becomes black.

To be more precise, I have a RichTextBox with a PrintDocument, PrintPreviewDialog, and so on. I can print without problem with this setup. The only thing is that my application has a dark theme (it is made to be used mainly by night) and the RichTextBox has a black background and the default text is white.

Therefore, when I print (or preview), the white text stays white and it can't be seen when printed...

I would then like to know how I would need to modify my components to change the font color from white to black upon printing. I do not care about other colors (they are the assumed choice of the user) that will be printed fine anyway.

Thanks so much for your pointers on this!

Comment: so are you handling the print event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your print handler,

```
var selection = myRichTextBox.Selection;
if (!selection.IsEmpty)
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: Okay, but this would turn all selected text to black right? My problem is that I print the RTF text, so I'd like to keep formatting and coloring of the rest of the text.

Comment: yes but after print is completed/ print preview is completed you can turn it back to white